# Pythonic conversion to singleton iterable if not already an iterable

Tags: python

Suppose I have

```
def distance2(vector1, vector2):
    zipped = zip(vector1, vector2)
    difference2 = [(vector2 - vector1) ** 2 for (vector1, vector2) in zipped]
    return sum(difference2)
```

where `distance2(vector1, vector2)` finds the (squared) Euclidian distance between `vector1` and `vector2`. The function will work for iterable elements, but suppose we also want to make it work for non-iterable elements (i.e. `distance2(1,3)`). Is there a pythonic way to do this? (i.e, automatically turning regular input into a singleton list).

Comment: Don't. It's much simpler for all concerned if the caller simply writes `distance([1], [2])`.

Comment: @chepner i agree although some builtins do work like this, e.g. `max()` takes an iterable or multiple args

Comment: @Chris_Rands The difference is that `max` doesn't operate based on the type of its first argument; it makes the decision based on how *many* positional arguments it gets. If it only gets one, it assumes it is an iterable. Consider the error you get with something like `max(1)`.

Comment: Doing the test inside the function adds overhead to *every single call* to `distance2`, even when the arguments are actually iterable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are describing the basic usage of [`always_iterable`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.always_iterable).

```
>>> from more_itertools.more import always_iterable
>>> for val in always_iterable(1):
...     print(val)
...     
1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy:

```
np.atleast_1d(1)
# array([1])

np.atleast_1d([1,2,3])
# array([1,2,3])
```